# Is Virtual Machine capable of running as normal PC would?

Tags: virtualbox, parallel-processing

Let's imagine that you have a super-powerful-server at home of size of desktop (just visualisation).

2048 physical cores each 3GHz, 64TB RAM, GTX 780 Ti Black Edition (SLIx4, (four graphics card working as one). I mean, seriously the really outrageously hardcore computer. *Yea, I know, it's impossible to have it in desktop, this is just helping you with visualisation of my question.*

Assuming that I would run Linux, I would install virtual machine client like VirtualBox or VMware and install Windows on it. I would give Windows:
- 6  of the Intel cores
- 32GB of RAM 1600MHz
- 1TB SSD

I would enable every setting like "Enable XYZ translation acceleration" and all "Boost 2D/3D graphics". Plainly, I would just enable any setting that would help boost performance of it. Both graphically as "processically".

Would such computer be capable of running advanced visual simulations with high framerate or run hardcore games on high settings with high framerate or for another example display 8K movie of 60FPS (if I had 8K monitor for that).

Answer (score 0):

Well it *is* possible however you would never install Linux and then a type 2 hypervisor you would install a type 1 (native) hypervisor such as Hyper-V or ESXi. This means they are at a lower level and have direct access to hardware whereas a type 2 hypervisor has to piggy back off the OS which isn't ideal.

Also 3D rendering or any GPU intense work is slightly different VMware ESXi has two features called VSGA and VDGA which directly talk to the GPU either dedicated (VDGA) or shared (VSGA). These features require specialistic hardware and do not work with standard home gaming cards.

But yes in reality with lots of money and skills you can get a virtual machine to do whatever you like.

Some games companies are already rolling out streaming online gaming websites where you can play the latest titles, all of these are running on virtual machines backend.

Hope this helps to answer your question a bit, its quite a large topic.

Comment: So Hyper-V and ESXi directly communicate to motherboard as if they were actual computers in literal dual-boot? | "These features require specialistic hardware", I think that Intel Xeon v2 E5-2697 does support that.

Comment: Hi RikTelner, yeah kinda like that I mean the Hypervisor acts like a layer between the VM and the hardware but much lower level than via an alternative OS like Linux. The specialist hardware is more for GPU rather than CPU, most CPU's work with visualization however GPU's are more limited. Have a google on nvidia GRID these are what I have been rolling out to clients recently.